# align-self is not located at the end of the container and it has space available to do so

Tags: css

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I want the word "content" to be at the end of the container using flexbox.

```
|1|     content|
```

thank you.

[image]

this is my live code:

https://jsfiddle.net/0tunwopb/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container_flex">
    <div>
      1
    </div>
    <div class="container_content">
      content
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.container_flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.container_flex div{
  border:1px solid red;
}

.container_content{
  flex-grow:1;
  align-self:flex-end;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.container_content` element is *already* flush up against the right-hand edge of `.container_flex`.

If you want the text *content* to align to the right, you're looking for **[`text-align: right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)**:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container_flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container_flex div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container_content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container_flex">
    <div>
      1
    </div>
    <div class="container_content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```